# Weekly Gmail autoReply

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Hope all is good. Just looking for any suggestions for this so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I use gmail with my own domain for my email client. I need to have an automatic weekly auto responder that starts on Friday evening at 7pm and continues to Monday morning 7am.

The script I have so far only defines days so I have it for Saturday and Sunday. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can be more accurate by adding times and not just full days.

See script I have so far below:

```
function autoReply() {
   var interval = 5;          //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
   var daysOff = [6,0];   // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
   var message = "I'm currently out of the office.";
   var date = new Date();
   var day = date.getDay();
   if (daysOff.indexOf(day) > -1) {
     var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
     var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
     for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
       threads[i].reply(message);
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save several headaches by moving the processed emails from the inbox, so after your script runs, the search will find only unprocessed email messages.

Regarding the specific question, the [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) doesn't include information to specify time, just dates. An alternative is check the required datetime against the value returned by [getDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getDate()).